# Match only the nth occurrence using a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with 3 dates in it like this:

```
XXXXX_20160207_20180208_XXXXXXX_20190408T160742_xxxxx
```

I want to select the 2nd date in the string, the `20180208` one.

Is there away to do this purely in the `regex`, with have to resort to pulling out the 2 match in code. I'm using `C#` if that matters.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Best way is to split on `_` and grab `x` occurrence.

Comment: Doing this in regex alone, however, you can use `(?<=^(?:[^_]+_){2})[^_]+`

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
^(?:[^_]+_){2}(\d+)
```

And take the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/09PxAP/1/).

---

Broken down, this says

```
^              # start of the string
(?:[^_]+_){2}  # not _ + _, twice
(\d+)          # capture digits
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/1iTG4J):

```
var pattern = @"^(?:[^_]+_){2}(\d+)"; 
var text = "XXXXX_20160207_20180208_XXXXXXX_20190408T160742_xxxxx";
var result = Regex.Match(text, pattern)?.Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(result); // => 20180208
```

Comment: `^(?:([^_]*)_){3}` and capture the 1st group would also work since only the last match of a group is captured. Not that it it better.

Comment: @Aaron: Feel free to post it as an alternative answer as it works as well.

Comment: Meh, better use yours IMO,13 steps vs 19 for mine in regex101. It was more to showcase a regex feature than anything.

Comment: Your regex gives an incorrect result if the string begins with the first date or if the dates are positioned differently in the string. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DQBnnh/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

> MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sInputLine, @"\d{8}");
>
> string sSecond = matches[1].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regular expression

```
^(?:.*?\d{8}_){1}.*?(\d{8})
```

to save the 2<sup>nd</sup> date to capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qbdQ0S/2/)

Naturally, for `n > 2`, replace `{1}` with `{n-1}` to obtain the n<sup>th</sup> date. To obtain the 1<sup>st</sup> date use

```
^(?:.*?\d{8}_){0}.*?(\d{8})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qbdQ0S/3/)

The C#'s regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^        # match the beginning of a line
(?:      # begin a non-capture group
  .*?    # match 0+ chars lazily
  \d{8}  # match 8 digits
  _      # match '_'
)        # end non-capture group
{n}      # execute non-capture group n (n >= 0) times
.*?      # match 0+ chars lazily     
(\d{8})  # match 8 digits in capture group 1
```

The important thing to note is that the first instance of `.*?`, followed by `\d{8}`, because it is lazy, will gobble up as many characters as it can until the next 8 characters are digits (and are not preceded or followed by a digit. For example, in the string

```
_1234abcd_efghi_123456789_12345678_ABC
```

capture group 1 in `(.*?)_\d{8}_` will contain `"_1234abcd_efghi_123456789"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

See the following example

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:[^_]+_){2}(\d+)"); //Expression from Jan's answer just showing how to use C# to achieve your goal
GroupCollection groups = regex.Match("XXXXX_20160207_20180208_XXXXXXX_20190408T160742_xxxxx").Groups;
if (groups.Count > 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Copying my expression and putting it as an answer one hour later?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't mean the copy your exp, but to show how to use c# code to use it