# How do I return only the nth match using a regular expression?

Tags: regex

So I'm looking at a string like this with a | delimiter:

`XL231241424|AB|ABCDE|LK|Word|A Phrase|Another random phrase|GH49|Example|31/02/2020|05/03/2020|N/A|N/A|N/A`

The end goal is to pluck specific items from this string and concatenate them together, essentially giving a more concise bit of text for readable in a reporting platform.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555593/regular-expression-capture-nth-match) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914235/match-only-the-nth-occurrence-using-a-regular-expression) but couldn't get it to work for my string. The match is simple, it's just:
`([^\|]*)` but how do I then just pull a match in position x? Specifically, if I want to get `Another random phrase` which is position 7, how do I do that?

Any help is much appreciated and an explanation is even better!

Thanks.

Comment: u tried with which programming language?

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914235) shows you how to do that

Comment: @Jan, I don't think this question warrants closure. The earlier question you cite is different (and more complex), as it seeks the nth substring that has a particular property; this question merely requires that pipes be counted. Moreover, even if a solution to the earlier question could be applied here I was unable to find any that were correct. I therefore request that you reverse your closing of this question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Well then, go for it.

Comment: Another dupe - [regex to match substring after nth occurence of pipe character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210118/regex-to-match-substring-after-nth-occurence-of-pipe-character).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, in my comment to Jan, I meant that I didn’t think this question warranted closure based on the earlier question he cited. You have shown it to be a dup, however, and I certainly have no problem with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){6}([^|]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y8uvLL/3/)

In your example `Another random phrase` would be saved to capture group 1.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^          # match beginning of line
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  [^|]*\|  # match 0+ chars other than '|' followed by '|'
)          # end non-capture group
{6}        # execute non-capture group 6 times
([^|]*)    # match 0+ chars other than '|' in capture group 1
```

If your regex engine supports `\K` (as does PCRE (PHP), P and others), you don't need a capture group:

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){6}\K[^|]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y8uvLL/2/)

In your example this matches `Another random phrase`.

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){6}\K[^|]*
```

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^          # match beginning of line
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  [^|]*\|  # match 0+ chars other than '|' followed by '|'
)          # end non-capture group
{6}        # execute non-capture group 6 times
\K         # discard everything matched so far
[^|]*      # match 0+ chars other than '|'
```

Comment: Thanks, Cary! This works perfectly. Appreciate the explanation of the operations too!